# NGINX access multiple sites same IP url

Tags: php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I would like to know how I can have several sites on Nginx and be able to access each of them with the same IP (without the domain, since I am doing tests in a laboratory locally).

I have the server on a separate PC and I access it remotely from my computer using the IP. Both are on the same LAN.

In the directory /var/www/ I have two sites 'nextcloud' and 'phpmyadmin'. I would like to be able to enter both by placing (for example) 192.168.1.14/nextcloud and 192.168.1.14/phpmyadmin. Or having any other project in the www directory.

I tried all the solutions I found, but none of them worked for me. When I enter phpmyadmin for example, it gives me to download the page instead of entering it.

Within /etc/nginx/sites-enabled I have the two files, one from nextcloud:

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/nextcloud/;

        index  index.php index.html index.htm;

        server_name  localhost;

        client_max_body_size 512M;
        fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

        location / {
            root /var/www/nextcloud;
        rewrite ^ /index.php$request_uri;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
            deny all;
        }
        location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
            deny all;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:index|remote|public|cron|core/ajax/update|status|ocs/v[12]|updater/.+|ocs-provider/.+)\.php(?:$|/) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
            fastcgi_request_buffering off;
        }

        location ~ ^/(?:updater|ocs-provider)(?:$|/) {
            try_files $uri/ =404;
            index index.php;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:css|js|woff|svg|gif)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=15778463";
            access_log off;
        }

        location ~ \.(?:png|html|ttf|ico|jpg|jpeg)$ {
            try_files $uri /index.php$request_uri;
            # Optional: Don't log access to other assets
            access_log off;
        }
    }
```

And that of phpmyadmin:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/phpmyadmin/;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        #
        #   # With php-fpm (or other unix sockets):
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        #   # With php-cgi (or other tcp sockets):
        #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }
    }
```

Try creating two test folders in /var/www/ (test1 and test2), each with an index.html file inside and modifying the nginx default file, but it didn't work for me either

```
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name localhost;

        index index.html;

        location / {
            return 410;  # Default root of site won't exist.
        }

        location /test1/ {
            alias /var/www/test1/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            # any additional configuration for non-static content
        }

        location /test2/ {
            alias /var/www/test2/;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;

            # any additional configuration for non-static content
        }
    }
```

As I said, I tried different solutions. Another problem I had was that it only redirected me to nextcloud, although I put phpmyadmin in the url. And the previous one that I already mentioned, that when I enter, download the index.php. Thank you.

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Simple add nextcloud.my and phpmyadmin.my to your `.hosts` file and listen domain name in Nginx. 
The option that you proposed can also be made to work, but it is full of bugs and difficulties can occur during the transfer to work server.